# Received offer via email but no response from HR afterwards

Tags: communication, job-search, job-offer

I did an internship at a company and at the end of the internship I received very positive feedback. After the internship, I got in contact with HR (the same person who offered me the internship) via email and she offered me a job offer for next year. After talking with her over the phone, I sent an email accepting the offer. However, she did not reply to my confirmation. I sent 2 follow up emails and gave her a phone call, and she eventually replied that she had been really busy and she would give me a call the next day (this was the same time that our city had begun to go under lockdown due to Covid-19 so it was quite a busy time). However I did not get any call and haven't got any response from my follow up emails.

Now, I have seen that she had recently moved to another company. What should I do?

- Is it appropriate to ask someone I know from the company and ask them for the contact details of the new HR person? It is a smallish company, so most of the people still know/remember me.
- Would I be able to ask the new HR person about this job offer? Would they be able to do anything about it?

**Edit:**

Following suggestions of looking at previously asked questions, I would like clarify my question. My main concern is the fact the HR person who offered me the job has left the company. This is a smallish company, so they only have 1 HR person. I would like to know what is my next course of action. I have already had a look at similar questions on this site and I don't believe they would apply to this exact situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: @gnat I don't believe this answers my question. My question is not about how long I should wait before contacting HR again (this is what the accepted answer talks about). My main concern is the fact that the original HR person who offered me the job has left the company and I am not sure what my next course of action should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You contact someone else**

OK, so the one (as far as you know) HR person left.  So you try to contact someone else.  Perhaps a manager you worked with during your internship.  Perhaps any contact email they have on their Web site.

It's possible they are going all the way under to the point that the offer's not valid any more and few to zero people are still working there; or maybe they're doing OK and the HR person left for normal reasons, or something in between.  In any event, you try to contact them via any means.  You also probably shouldn't count on that job offer and make sure to have other irons in the fire.

I'm not sure what else to say.  Call somebody already.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just want to add, there is definitely only 1 HR person for that branch. Also the company has been performing quite well over the past few months. Actually, it seems like the Covid-19 situation has given them more projects to work on and they have been hiring more people over the past few months (I follow the company on Linkedin which is how I know this). So I don't think the company is doing badly is the reason why they haven't followed up on my job offer. But yes, I will follow your advice and try calling someone.

Comment: also just want to ask, do you think it is better that I try to contact the new HR person, or I talk to a manager I have worked with before?

Comment: Any and all.  If there is a new HR person then obviously them, but there may not be one.